# Highcharts - cylinder Chart

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

I want to create a cylinder highchart as shown in the pic.

Is there any built in chart or de we have to write a custom chart ? A good example is most appreciated.

[image]

Comment: At this moment this functionality requires custom code and is feature request, posted in our uservoice service here: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/7333994-have-an-option-that-transform-3d-column-charts-int . I advice you to vote for it.

Comment: From a user experience perspective, I would suggest against using cylinder charts to show data. The curved edges and warped y-axis can make it difficult for your users to see the precise measurements of each cylinder's sections, unless you annotate them with labels.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality was not available when the question was asked. So, **Sebastian Bochan** raised a [question](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/7333994-have-an-option-that-transform-3d-column-charts-int?tracking_code=2bb33bf6252b48d0e3638ec879e48ddf) with Highcharts on Aug 22 '16. Now the [feature](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/3d-cylinder) is available in  Highcharts 7.